# What tense stops Latin imperfect ("action continuing in the past")

Tags: grammar-choice

Can Latin imperfect be "stopped" in the past or only in the present?

[from A&G 471.b](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/imperfect-tense):

> b. With *iam diū*, *iam dūdum*, and other expressions of duration of time,
> the imperfect denotes an action continuing in the past but begun at
> some previous time (cf. § 466). In this construction the imperfect is
> rendered by the English pluperfect.
>
> > Iam dūdum flēbam. (Ov. M. 3.656) I had been weeping for a long time.
>
> > cōpiās quās diū comparābant (Fam. 11.13.5) the forces which they had
> > long been getting ready

To judge by the Ovid example it then followed by present tense (*:lacrimas manus inpia nostras
**ridet** et **inpellit** properantibus aequora remis*); while the Cicero example it followed by the perfect tense (*subito ad patriae periculum **converterunt.***).

Specifically, In Cicero there are versions that read *compararant* (pluperfect) and not *comparabant*. Is the imperfect valid or natural choice despite being stopped in the past? or the pluperfect has to be preferred? What are other examples?

Comment: Are you really asking for every possible tense corresponding with every possible time every possible action might end? or did you have any more specific request? As it stands, the answer is "all of them, depending".

Comment: @lly, I ask if *iamdiu flebam donec(?) te vidi* is valid. If so, I would like to know what might be the difference between using *video*.(*... sed nunc te video*) According to A&G 66, if we use the present tense instead of the imperfect *iamdiu fleo* it means that the action still happening and haven't stopped yet. But if we use the imperfect it suggests I believe the action has already stopped: I ask can it be stopped in the past? (we might not even provide additional verbs.); or merely using this construction implies this stopped only now?

Comment: If you look at more of the the Ovid passage, you'll see that those present tense verbs are the 'historical present,' representing the perfect. Practically speaking, the imperfect in both examples is followed by a perfect.

Comment: @cnread, interesting. But now we are left with the question of if the imperfect *felbam* is not "historical imperfect" (if there is such a thing) representing the pluperfect? :)

Comment: @cnread: In this answer from Seb, =https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16328/1982, should (historical) present, "minatur", be seen as a perfect tense? The complementary verb, "restituissent", is a pluperfect-subjunctive being used to represent the future. The anteriority, Seb describes, is perfect then pluperfect (originally future-perfect), is that correct?

Comment: @tony, I'm not seeing what that has to do with the current question, which involves no subjunctives; so sequence of tenses and the behavior of conditions in complex constructions don't apply at all. Maybe your comment would be better as a separate question?

Comment: @cnread: It was the point about the historic present representing the perfect. The pluperfect-subjunctive being used to represent the future, in indirect speech, takes a bit of understanding (the OP, here, is also concerned about timings). That historic present, "minatur", should be seen as a perfect makes Seb's analysis of anteriority much clearer.